# Weird behavior of tensorflow tf.cast

Tags: python, tensorflow

Has anyone got strange behavior of `tf.cast` between integers and unsigned integers? I run the following example (on `https://colab.research.google.com`):

```
import tensorflow as tf

c = tf.constant([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], dtype=tf.int32)
x = tf.cast(c, dtype=tf.uint32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    x_raw = sess.run(x)
    print(x_raw.dtype)
    print(x_raw)

print(tf.__version__)
```

and get the result:

```
uint32
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
1.14.0-rc1
```

Have I used the cast in a wrong way? Or is there some bug for type casting in TF?

------------------ UPDATE ------------------

Some people might have run above code and get a correct result. Actually I also got the correct one when I run it only once (in a notebook cell), but if you run the cell again, it would surprise you. Perhaps a better way to recreate the event is to run the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

c = tf.constant([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], dtype=tf.int32)
d = tf.constant([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], dtype=tf.int32)
x = tf.cast(c, dtype=tf.uint32)
y = tf.cast(c, dtype=tf.uint32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    x_raw, y_raw = sess.run([x, y])
    print(x_raw.dtype, y_raw.dtype)
    print(x_raw)
    print(y_raw)

print(tf.__version__)
```

This would guarantee an error in my case. It seems like something really smelly is going on in the TF runtime...

Comment: That's strange. I get `[ 5  6  7  8  9 10]` with TF 1.14.0

Comment: @rvinas, thanks for the trying, could you also check my update above? I also tested this with TF 1.13.1, no luck :(

Comment: Ouch, I get the error too. It seems like a bug. Would you like to try if it works with the latest TF version? If it doesn't, it would be worth reporting this. I can do it too, if you want

Comment: @rvinas, I submitted this issue for TF 1.14.0 and 1.13.1 on their github. I haven't tried this with TF 2.0